# Is the "nonzero-measure" projection $\{x \mid \mu(\{y \mid (x, y) \in S\}) > 0\}$ of a zero measure closed subset closed?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a measurable space, and $S \subseteq X \times X$ has zero measure and is closed. Then, consider the set $T = \{x \mid \{y \mid (x, y) \in S\} \text{ has nonzero measure in }X\}$. It seems to me that this has zero measure. Is it furthermore closed? I have been pondering it and cannot find a counterexample (each time I try I find a reason why $S$ is not closed). If not, does its closure have zero measure?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a counterexample where $T$ is not closed. Let $X = [0,1]$ be endowed with the standard topology and the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. For each positive integer $n$, define the set

$$ S_n = \{\frac{1}{n}\} \times [0, \frac1n] \subseteq X \times X.$$

Then put

$$ S =  ( \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_n ) \cup \{(0,0)\}.$$

Geometrically, the set $S$ consists of countably many vertical lines, and the lines become shorter when we go left. The limit point $(0,0)$ is included in $S$; so $S$ is closed. Also, $S$ is a zero-set, since each of the countably many lines $S_n$ has measure $0$ in $X \times X$. The set $T$ from the OP's definition is

$$ T = \{\frac1n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} $$

in this context, so is not closed.

Comment: Nice! This is what I was thinking (except I didn't remember I could just add the point $(0,0)$). What about the second part; can the closure have nonzero measure? Here, it still has zero measure.

Comment: @RobinAldabanx I'd be surprised if you find one. (But until now it's just intuition.)